# The proper/best way to reference a git local fork of an open source library from a Visual Studio solution using Team Foundation Version Control

Tags: git, version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I have a VS solution that uses Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC, centralized version controla) as well as an open source library hosted in a git repo.

I had the need to modify that library so I made a local fork.

I forecast that I will need to continue to make changes to this library.

How should I reference this library from my VS solution that uses TFVC?

I believe I have to options:

- Add the project of the open source library directly to my VS solution. This is cumbersome since most of my solution is on TFVC and this one project is on GIT. Every time I open the solution VS complaints about not being able to find the source control information of the open source project. In addition, if I ever try to get the source control of my solution from another machine it will be incomplete (missing the changes on the open source library)
- Reference only the DLL of the modified open source library. However, since I plan to continue to make changes to this library it seems like this will be a cumbersome and inefficient process.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to produce a nuget package from the open source project and host that on a local nuget server or file share. Reference that package from your TFVC project and turn on package restore.

As long as other devs have set visual studio to use the local nuget feed (and you adjust your build server) they'll pick up the DLLs automatically.